In Oracle, how to replace surplus part of string by a dot?
My requirement is following simple handling of strings using Oracle 23c:

If the string is NULL or has a length <= 5, it should be returned as it is.
Otherwise, the first 4 characters followed by a dot should be returned, the rest should be removed.

So for following sample input data...
CREATE TABLE test (col VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
  ('hello!'), ('world'), ('worl.'), ('x'), ('long text'), ('alsotoolong'), (NULL);




COL




hello!


world


worl.


x


long text


alsotoolong


null



...following result must be returned:



COL




hell.


world


worl.


x


long.


also.


null



I was able to get the expected outcome with following query:
SELECT
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(col) > 5 
    THEN SUBSTR(col,1,4) || '.' 
    ELSE col END AS col
FROM test;

What I just wonder is if we really need a CASE expression here to check the length. I guess there should be a more trivial way which is shorter and better to read. A solution that just replaces the rest after the fourth character by a dot in one step.
Maybe you have an idea?
I searched here on Stackoverflow and also generally in the net, but couldn't find something related to this use case, so sorry in case there is a duplicate question here which I haven't spotted or in case there is no simpler option.
Anyway, you can use this sample fiddle to try out possible solutions.

The case expression is the most readable way to do this in my opinion. I like Dogbert's answer, though. And a third option would be to write a PL/SQL function with a fancy name like "shorten_string".

This can be done with a regex replace function call, by matching strings of length 6 or more and replacing it with the first 4 characters plus a dot.
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(.{4}).{2,}', '\1.') AS col
FROM test;

Fiddle
This will probably be slower than a case + substring statement though.

Thanks to you and Thorsten! I will keep my current query, but really like your approach. It will likely be useful some day for similar tasks.

Solution without CASE and without regex exists, but is a bit tricky using decode (So not really better to read - you need a condition in your expression).
substr(col,1,4)||decode(substr(col,6),null,substr(col,5,1),'.')

Basically, if the string from the 6th character is null you add the 5th character to the first four, otherwise add a dot.
Example
with tab as (
select 'world!' col from dual union all
select 'world' col from dual union all
select 'worl' col from dual union all
select 'wor' col from dual union all
select null col from dual)
select substr(col,1,4), substr(col,5,1), substr(col,6),
substr(col,1,4)||decode(substr(col,6),null,substr(col,5,1),'.')
from tab

SUBS S S SUBST
---- - - -----
worl d ! worl.
worl d   world
worl     worl 
wor      wor  
null null null null

